# Typescript vs ES6 - TS2306: File '../src/app/model.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have two examples from Angular book, first (ES6) works, second (TypeScript) does not. I think TypeScript example is somehow broken:

**this one works - ES6 - model.ts**

```
export class Model {
  user;
  items;
  constructor() {
    this.user = "Adam";
    this.items = [
      new TodoItem("Buy things", false),
      new TodoItem("Get tickets", false),
      new TodoItem("Call", false),
    ]
  }
}

export class  TodoItem {
  action;
  done;

  constructor(action, done) {
    this.action = action;
    this.done = done;
  }
}
```

**this one does not work - TypeScript - model.ts**

```
var model = {
  user: "Adam",
  items: [
    { action: "Buy things", done: false},
    { action: "Get tickets", done: false},
    { action: "Call", done: false}
  ]
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Model }  from "./model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  model = new Model();

  getName() {
    return this.model.user;
  }
}
```

I also comment out `"strict": true` and added `"noImplicitAny": false` in **tsconfig.json**

TypeScript example gives me error in **app.component.ts** file within import Model line

```
TS2306: File '../src/app/model.ts' is not a module.
```

How to make TypeScript import variable example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found solution:

added export before variable in **model.ts**

```
export const model = {
  user: "Adam",
  items: [
    { action: "Buy things", done: false},
    { action: "Get tickets", done: false},
    { action: "Call", done: false},
  ]
};
```

And changed in **app.component.ts**

`import { Model }  from "./model";` to `import { model }  from "./model";`

`model = new Model();` to `model = model;`